# Is this a valid MVP Pattern Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns, mvp

I'm trying to analyse some code here that's been designed using an MVP Approach. No specific MVP Framework has been used. This is all hand-written code.

```
//Interface Representing our View
public interface IFooView
{
   string SomeScreenValue
}

//Presenter Implementation
public class FooPresenter 
{
    private readonly IFooView _view;

    public FooPresenter (IFooView view) 
    {
        //The presenter gets instantiated with a reference to a view.
        _view = view
    }

    public void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.SomeScreenValue = "The Result";
    }
}

//The Page Implementation
public class FooPage : System.Web.UI.Page, IFooView
{
    private FooPresenter _presenter;

    protected void Page_Init(...)
    {
        _presenter = new FooPresenter(this);  
        //<-- The View has a Presenter, which references the same View...
        Button1.Click += new EventHandler(_presener.SomeButton_Click);
    }
}
```

It works in that it allows the developer to move the business logic away from the code behind into classes, while still affecting the View. But the absense of an actual Model, and the way in which the View => Presenter => View relationship is setup is just a little irksome to me?

So is the above situation a valid implementation of the MVP Pattern ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *almost* MVP in that your Presenter is de-coupled from the view in such a way that when it updates the UI state it does so through the `IFooView` interface. However, having a method within your presenter that conforms to a standard .NET event handler seems wrong to me. I would make `IFooView` raise an event when a button click occurs, then your page can perform the task of handling the button click as you currently do, then raising the event which your Presenter handles. This event can be more closely related to the domain, for example you might want an event such as `RecordUpdated` exposed via your `IFooView`.

This will make it easier to provide a mock implementation of `IFooView` for unit testing, which is after all a big advantage of using an MVP / MVC / MVVM pattern.

If you do not have any data coming from a back-end service, or database, then in the case of simple applications it is OK for the Presenter to take on the role of the model as well. This is the case in your trivial example. The same can be done in MVVM, where the ViewModel can take on the Model responsibilities also. However, I would recommend creating a Model if you do anything non-trivial. In your case, the Presenter would delegate to the Model for maintaining state and would use some sort of 'service' to persist changes to this model, or retrieve model objects from web services.

Comment: So what exactly is the "Model" in this example. Or is the model just the loose grouping of different datasources used to get data from.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. the example above was distilled down from a simple UI screen that took 3 or 4 values from textboxes & DDLs, hit the DataAccess Manager with a Query and got back a result set that was then bound to a GridView. Subsequent calls could include paging & order clauses but it was essentially a simple Populate-GridView screen that called the DAL directly from the presenter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

But... 
I should change the presenter construction to FooPage constructor instead. Sometime you want to handle the preInit event and that´s not possible with this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, this is the "passive view" variant of model view presenter. In this variant, the view has no knowledge of the view whatsoever. The view is dumb and fully controlled by the presenter.

The MVP pattern was described by Fowler in 2004 and he [retired it in 2006](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html) by splitting the pattern into [supervising conroller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) (sc) and [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) (pv). In sc, the view is bound to the model and in pv not, in pv the view is only changed by the presenter directly.